# android - How to detect holding of buttons?

Tags: android, button

In android, how can I detect if a button is being held down? What I am trying to do is: If a button is held for 2 seconds then call some function, if its held for less than 2 seconds then call another function.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the [setOnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29) method for the View object in addition to setOnClickListener.